# Input in MULTI option do not produce expected output in dash python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to filter by Year with multi = True in dropdown option and get the output. 
I have managed to get output when I inputted in sequence 2018, 2019, 2020 or one by one.
If I choose  2018, 2019 or 2019, 2018 or any other sequence the graph doesn’t appear. 
Error produced: KeyError: False 
What I missed and how to get the dropdown work correctly?
My code is below.
Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

c = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
idx = 2018,2019,2020
df_group = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 12)),
                 columns=list(c), index=list(idx))
#df_group.index.names = ['Year']

year_options = []
for metai in df_group.index.unique():
    year_options.append({'label': str(metai), 'value': metai})

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='year-picker', multi=True, options=year_options, value=2019
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('year-picker', 'value')])

def update_figure(selected_year):
    data = []
    #for year in df_group.loc[df_group.index == selected_year].index.unique(): - bad code
    for year in selected_year:
        #print(year)
        trace = go.Scatter(
            x=df_group.columns,
            y=df_group.loc[year],
            mode='markers+lines',
            marker = {
                        'size': 12,
                        'line': {'width': 2}
                        }, 
            name=str(year)
            )
        data.append(trace)
    return {
        'data': data,
    'layout': go.Layout(
        title='Per Year, EUR'
    )}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I found my mistake. I passed the list to the loop in a bad and hard way.
The simplicity is that I should pass the list coming from input function. <br>That is all. 
I corrected my code. In any way thank you. SOLVED